# Strange gap in email newsletter that only appears on iPhones

Tags: iphone, html, css, email, newsletter

I'm developing an email newsletter and I have it looking good in all the email clients I need to test for (AOL, Hotmail, Yahoo, Gmail, Outlook, Lotus Notes, Thunderbird, etc.) except on iPhones. Even iPads look good, so it's not an iOS thing. I used a table-based layout and am using litmus.com to test.

Here's the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

And here's my table structure. (This is a nested table and only part of the newsletter.)

[image: screenshot]

Notice that the gap is only on one side.

Both images on the sides are the same height and both have the width and height declared in the `<img>` tag. I've dealt with gaps in email newsletters before. Adding `display:block;` and taking away physical spaces between `<tr>`'s and `<td>`'s usually does the trick, but I've tried and again, no luck.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Newsletter</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="margin:0 auto; width:650px;" width="650">
<tr><td colspan="2"><p align="right" style="font-size: 12px; line-height:18px;"><forwardtoafriend>Forward to a Friend</forwardtoafriend></p></td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0 auto; border-collapse:collapse;" align="center" width="650" bgcolor="#efe8d8">
        <tr><td><img src="images/header.jpg" alt="Description" width="650" height="110" style="display:block;" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="650">
                <tr><td colspan="3"><img src="images/hotter.jpg" alt="Description" width="650" height="144" border="0" style="display:block;" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td valign="top"><img src="images/letter-l.jpg" width="61" height="613" style="display:block;"></td><td width="495" height="613" bgcolor="#f7f4eb" style="height:613px;"><h3 style="margin:0 0 30px; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:18px;">Greetings,</h3>
                    <p style="margin:10px 0px; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#000; line-height:20px; font-size:14px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis metus quam, lacinia vehicula tellus. Donec a elementum est. Fusce et sem nec diam aliquam rhoncus non non orci. Phasellus tortor eros, aliquam et ultrices vel, mollis et ante. Sed id lectus at mi massa nunc.</p>
                    <p style="margin:10px 0px; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#000; line-height:20px; font-size:14px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu urna sed nisl aliquet pretium. Nullam mattis cursus nisi ut porttitor. Suspendisse ut lectus elit, ut placerat neque. Aliquam orci lacus, dictum accumsan euismod a, imperdiet sit amet lorem. Maecenas vitae justo nisi, non convallis tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia sed.</p>
                    <p style="margin:10px 0px; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#000; line-height:20px; font-size:14px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vestibulum pulvinar ullamcorper. Nulla varius pretium turpis vitae adipiscing. Proin suscipit, tortor interdum lobortis malesuada, quam arcu dictum sapien, in varius nulla quam a mi. Duis eget orci quis mi egestas sollicitudin. Vestibulum gravida odio et metus.</p>
                    <p style="margin:10px 0px; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#000; line-height:20px; font-size:14px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a erat nec est luctus consequat sed id erat. Duis odio sem, blandit sed malesuada eget, convallis commodo felis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam vitae fermentum augue. Nam a fermentum enim. In diam turpis volutpat.</p>
                    <p style="margin:10px 0px; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#000; line-height:20px; font-size:14px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac orci sed massa interdum suscipit. Proin facilisis venenatis lacus, sed cursus sem hendrerit ac. Sed tristique, nisi a nullam.</p></td><td valign="top"><img src="images/letter-r.jpg" width="94" height="613" style="display:block;"></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="3"><img src="images/letter-bottom.jpg" width="650" border="0" style="display:block;" /></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td><img src="images/star-rewards.jpg" alt="Description">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="650">
                <tr><td><a href="#"><img src="images/card-star.jpg" border="0"></a></td><td>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/header-star.jpg" border="0"></a>
                    <p style="margin:10px 30px 10px 0; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#636364; line-height:24px; font-size:14px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus molestie nulla vel lorem scelerisque hendrerit. Phasellus sed ullamcorper lorem. Phasellus molestie convallis aliquet. Proin justo magna, aliquam amet.</p></td></tr>
                <tr><td><a href="#"><img src="images/card-sky.jpg" border="0"></a></td><td>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/header-sky.jpg" border="0"></a>
                    <p style="margin:10px 30px 10px 0; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#636364; line-height:24px; font-size:14px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vel est nec nibh imperdiet suscipit ornare porta enim. Aenean lobortis orci at ligula sollicitudin semper. Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur mollis tellus ut sem consequat placerat. Cras amet.</p></td></tr>
                <tr><td><a href="#"><img src="images/card-wind.jpg" border="0"></a></td><td>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/header-wind.jpg" border="0"></a>
                    <p style="margin:10px 30px 10px 0; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#636364; line-height:24px; font-size:14px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis quam vel orci pharetra tempus ut quis neque. Duis condimentum magna ut lorem vulputate et dapibus ipsum facilisis. Nullam rutrum rhoncus massa, ut viverra risus luctus eget. Fusce nullam.</p></td></tr>
                <tr><td><a href="#"><img src="images/card-water.jpg" border="0"></a></td><td>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/header-water.jpg" border="0"></a>
                    <p style="margin:10px 30px 10px 0; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#636364; line-height:24px; font-size:14px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum libero mauris, porttitor ac placerat blandit, sodales quis diam. Suspendisse at est ante. Integer et porta lacus. Ut egestas elementum metus.</p></td></tr>
                <tr><td><a href="#"><img src="images/card-earth.jpg" border="0"></a></td><td>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/header-earth.jpg" border="0"></a>
                    <p style="margin:10px 30px 10px 0; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#636364; line-height:24px; font-size:14px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent venenatis erat id nibh ultrices vehicula. Quisque interdum posuere ante at aliquam. Nullam sed lectus ut ipsum rutrum lacinia malesuada massa nunc.</p>
                </td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><p style="margin:10px 30px 10px 0; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#636364; line-height:20px; font-size:12px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean laoreet tincidunt ipsum eget ultricies. Etiam bibendum elementum mollis. Pellentesque eleifend sollicitudin tincidunt. Proin nulla felis, congue at nullam.</p></td>
            </table>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3" style="padding:0;margin:0;line-height:0;"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Description" /></td></tr><tr><td style="padding:0;margin:0;line-height:0;"><img style="padding:0;margin:0;line-height:0;" src="images/footer-l.jpg" /><a style="padding:0;margin:0;line-height:0;" href="#"><img style="padding:0;margin:0;line-height:0; border:none;" src="images/footer-url.jpg" alt="Description" /></a><img style="padding:0;margin:0;line-height:0;" src="images/footer-r.jpg" /></td></tr><tr><td style="padding:0;margin:0;line-height:0;"><img src="images/footer-bottom.jpg" /></td></tr><tr><td style="padding:0;margin:0;line-height:0;"><img src="images/follow.jpg" alt="Follow us on Twitter and Facebook!" /><a href="#"><img style="border:none;" src="images/twitter.jpg" alt="#" /></a><a href="#"><img style="border:none;" src="images/facebook.jpg" alt="Facebook" /></a></td></tr></table><tr><td colspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><p align="center" style="font-size: 12px; line-height:18px;"><unsubscribe>Unsubscribe</unsubscribe> or <preferences>Change your Email Address</preferences></p>
</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT: I've updated it with the full code. However I've changed the link href's, image descriptions, and the copy out of respect of the client. Each paragraph of dummy text is the same character count as the original. The problem cell is the one containing letter-l.jpg.**

Comment: Sometimes it's white-space in-between HTML elements causing this.

Comment: It might be helpful to create a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Diodeus I've already taken away all the white spaces. (That's what I meant by "physical space".)

Comment: Does it appear this way on Safari mobile, or just in the mail client?

Comment: @Diodeus I won't have access to Safari mobile until later tonight (my iPod Touch at home). As I've said above, I've been testing with litmus.com.

Comment: I use extacttarget.com's advanced preview generator.

Comment: @Diodeus Unfortunately, the company I work for only has an account with litmus so that's what I'm bound to.

Comment: @Marcin It's fine in all browsers. It's just the iPhone mail client that has issues. I don't think jsfiddle can simulate that, can it?

Comment: @jaypea07 It can't simulate it, but it can make it a lot easier to understand your code.

Comment: Post the full code, could be many things...

Comment: I updated with the full code. See my edit note for details.

Answer (score 0):

usually just removing the bgcolor from TDs and adding it to tables resolves this issue. Strange thing is today I've got into the same problem and my fix is not working anymore :(

Comment: I've had this issue come up a few more times since this post and I still don't have a solution for this. Were you able to find anything?